Mysql rows transposing in Node.js with mysql2
I am running an SQL script in Node.js using mysql2 npm-package. This script has multiple SQL statements that have to ultimately transpose a table's rows into columns. The SQL script runs correctly when run on phpmyadmin however i'm getting a "ER_PARSE_ERROR" when I try to use the SQL script in node.js in a string.
The problem is not transposing the table, I have already achieved that, the problem is that mysql2 cannot Parse my SQL statement.
Enabling "multipleStatements: true" and other solutions of concatenating my SQL statement has not worked for me because my SQL statement is a complex one it's not a simple SQL statement as those given in questions similar to mine.
var mysql2 = require("mysql2/promise");

var connection_retry_counter = 0;

var connmysql = null;

async function dbconnector() {
connmysql = mysql2.createPool({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    maxIdle: 10, // max idle connections, the default value is the same as `connectionLimit`
    idleTimeout: 60000, // idle connections timeout, in milliseconds, the default value 60000
    queueLimit: 0,
    enableKeepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
    multipleStatements: true
});


    connmysql
    .getConnection()
    .then(function(conn) {
        console.log("connected to database successfully on port::", conn.config.port);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        if (err.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
            if (connection_retry_counter >= 10) {
                console.log("database on port:: ", err.port , " cannot be reached");
            } else {
                ++connection_retry_counter;

                dbconnector();
                console.log("re-trying to connect to database on port::", err.port , " trial ", connection_retry_counter);
            }
            
        }
    });  
};

dbconnector();

module.exports = connmysql;

var connmysql = require("./../../configs/configMysql");
var commons = require("./../../utils/commonFunctions");
var constants = require("./../../constants");


exports.generate_report = async function(req, res) {
    var sql = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;";
    
    sql += "SET @dynamic_columns = NULL;";
    sql += "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN EmplyoeeTransactions_01.payitemcode = \"', payitemcode, '\" THEN amount END) AS \"', payitemcode, '\"') ) INTO @dynamic_columns FROM EmplyoeeTransactions_01;";
    
    sql += "SET @dynamic_sql = CONCAT('SELECT \"', @dynamic_columns, '\", classification_group_name,classification_list_name, tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code, emp_first_name, emp_middle_name, emp_last_name, emp_phone_number, emp_email_address, emp_nationality, emp_gender, emp_date_of_birth, emp_employment_number, emp_employment_type, emp_date_of_entry, emp_house_type, emp_disability_status, emp_designation, emp_residence, emp_profile_picture, emp_uuid, emp_uuid_status, emp_termination_date, emp_termination_reason, emp_status, emp_payroll_code FROM tbl_company_employees_01 LEFT JOIN tbl_com_emp_classifications_01 ON tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.emp_code = tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code LEFT JOIN tbl_emp_classification_01 ON tbl_emp_classification_01.classification_group_code = tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.classification_group_code LEFT JOIN tbl_emp_classification_lists_01 ON tbl_emp_classification_lists_01.classification_list_code = tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.classification_list_code LEFT JOIN EmplyoeeTransactions_01 ON EmplyoeeTransactions_01.empcode = tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code LEFT JOIN PayItems_01 ON PayItems_01.payitemcode = EmplyoeeTransactions_01.payitemcode GROUP BY empcode');";
    
    sql += "PREPARE stmt FROM @dynamic_sql;";
    sql += "EXECUTE stmt;";
    sql += "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

    
    try {
        var [ rows ] = await connmysql.query(sql, null);

        res.status(200).json(rows);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Error generate_report: ", err);

        if (err.code === 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE') {
            return commons.sendresponseObject(res, 500, "Could not fetch report, reporting not set.");
        }
        commons.send500Error(res, err);
    }
};

{
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Server error, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1",
    "error": {
        "message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1",
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sql": "\n        SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;\n\n        SET @dynamic_columns = NULL;\n\n        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\n            DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN EmplyoeeTransactions_01.payitemcode = \"', payitemcode, '\" THEN amount END) AS \"', payitemcode, '\"')\n        ) INTO @dynamic_columns\n        FROM EmplyoeeTransactions_01;\n\n        SET @dynamic_sql = CONCAT(\n            'SELECT ', @dynamic_columns, ',\n            classification_group_name,classification_list_name,\n            tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code, emp_first_name, emp_middle_name, emp_last_name, emp_phone_number, emp_email_address, emp_nationality, \n            emp_gender, emp_date_of_birth, emp_employment_number, emp_employment_type, emp_date_of_entry, emp_house_type, emp_disability_status, \n            emp_designation, emp_residence, emp_profile_picture, emp_uuid, emp_uuid_status, emp_termination_date, emp_termination_reason, emp_status, emp_payroll_code  \n            FROM tbl_company_employees_01\n            LEFT JOIN tbl_com_emp_classifications_01\n            ON tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.emp_code = tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code\n            LEFT JOIN tbl_emp_classification_01\n            ON tbl_emp_classification_01.classification_group_code = tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.classification_group_code\n            LEFT JOIN tbl_emp_classification_lists_01\n            ON tbl_emp_classification_lists_01.classification_list_code = tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.classification_list_code\n            LEFT JOIN EmplyoeeTransactions_01\n            ON EmplyoeeTransactions_01.empcode = tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code\n            LEFT JOIN PayItems_01\n            ON PayItems_01.payitemcode = EmplyoeeTransactions_01.payitemcode GROUP BY empcode'\n        );\n\n        PREPARE stmt FROM @dynamic_sql;\n        EXECUTE stmt;\n        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;\n    ",
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1"
    }
}

Here is the one with template literal.
var connmysql = require("./../../configs/configMysql");
var commons = require("./../../utils/commonFunctions");
var constants = require("./../../constants");


exports.generate_report = async function(req, res) {
    var sql = `
        SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

        SET @dynamic_columns = NULL;

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN EmplyoeeTransactions_01.payitemcode = "', payitemcode, '" THEN amount END) AS "', payitemcode, '"')
        ) INTO @dynamic_columns
        FROM EmplyoeeTransactions_01;

        SET @dynamic_sql = CONCAT(
            'SELECT ', @dynamic_columns, ',
            classification_group_name,classification_list_name,
            tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code, emp_first_name, emp_middle_name, emp_last_name, emp_phone_number, emp_email_address, emp_nationality, 
            emp_gender, emp_date_of_birth, emp_employment_number, emp_employment_type, emp_date_of_entry, emp_house_type, emp_disability_status, 
            emp_designation, emp_residence, emp_profile_picture, emp_uuid, emp_uuid_status, emp_termination_date, emp_termination_reason, emp_status, emp_payroll_code  
            FROM tbl_company_employees_01
            LEFT JOIN tbl_com_emp_classifications_01
            ON tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.emp_code = tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code
            LEFT JOIN tbl_emp_classification_01
            ON tbl_emp_classification_01.classification_group_code = tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.classification_group_code
            LEFT JOIN tbl_emp_classification_lists_01
            ON tbl_emp_classification_lists_01.classification_list_code = tbl_com_emp_classifications_01.classification_list_code
            LEFT JOIN EmplyoeeTransactions_01
            ON EmplyoeeTransactions_01.empcode = tbl_company_employees_01.emp_code
            LEFT JOIN PayItems_01
            ON PayItems_01.payitemcode = EmplyoeeTransactions_01.payitemcode GROUP BY empcode'
        );

        PREPARE stmt FROM @dynamic_sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    `;
    
    try {
        var [ rows ] = await connmysql.query(sql, null);

        res.status(200).json(rows);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Error generate_report: ", err);

        if (err.code === 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE') {
            return commons.sendresponseObject(res, 500, "Could not fetch report, reporting not set.");
        }
        commons.send500Error(res, err);
    }
};

I'm try to actually run the script in Node.js and hence transpose a table's rows to columns.

Duplicate of node-mysql multiple statements in one query. I highly recommend searching before posting a new question

I have read those questions about multipleStatements, and I have implemented the suggestions, however my SQL statement is not a simple SQL statement please look at it closer because the suggested solutions have not worked for me.

Why did you move away from a template literal? The string concatenation seems much more difficult to get right

My intention was to show that I have tried to implement the solutions from the duplicate

Just do one at a time, namely the multipleStatements: true. I'm not sure why you would think you'd need to change the way you construct the string

desperate attempt to ave it work I guess. But i'm sticking with template literals.

the error message is the same.

any suggestion on how to fix this?

Sorry no, but I've voted to re-open your question. Out of interest, does it run as a plain old .sql script? eg mysql -h $MYSQL_HOST -u $MYSQL_USER -p $MYSQL_DATABASE < script.sql (not through phpMyAdmin)

Actually, I have a funny feeling you're trying to use 'NULL' somewhere in your dynamic query. You should dump out @dynamic_sql for debugging.

@johnk.w On SO you get answers to the specific question you asked, which may not be the full solution you are looking for. You should ask a new question with the modified script including the new error message. The parse error message should change indicating a new place where the error occurs. Note: I would not do reporting this way at all. Pull the data over to the application side and construct the dynamic query there. Or even better: use a proper reporting tool for generating pivot tables.
